# Prime counts with maximal prime spacing.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I think this question is related to Maier's theorem but I am unsure.

Notation: $\pi(x)$ is the prime-counting function up to $x$. $g_k := p_{k+1} - p_k$.

Define $M_n$ to be the $n$th maximal gap between primes. That is, $M_n = g_i$, where $p_i$ is the smallest prime such that $g_i > g_j$ for all $j < i$. Define $x_n := $smallest $x$ where $m_n := max(\pi(x+M_n)-\pi(x))$ for all $x$ between $p_i$ of $M_{n-1}$ to the $p_i$ of $M_n$ occurs.

In other words, using the spacing between maximal primes as a section, what is the maximum count of primes for each section? And, where is it? Does the count $m_n$ go to infinity? At what rate does it grow? Clearly, $\pi(x+M_n)-\pi(x)$ is greater than 1 up to the maximal prime where is it 1. What happens with $m_n/M_n$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671337/bounding-maximal-gaps-with-ramanujan-primes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does the count $m_n$ go to infinity? At what rate does it grow?**

Heuristically, yes, $m_n$ goes to infinity; assuming that the [Cramer and Shanks conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer_conjecture#Related_conjectures_and_heuristics) are true for almost all maximal prime gaps, we can expect that $m_n$ goes to infinity *at least as fast as* $\log x_n$. That's because

(i) we almost always have $M_n\sim\log^2 x_n$ by the Cramer and Shanks conjectures;

(ii) the *average* count of primes in the interval $[x,x+M_n]$ (for $x$ near $x_n$) is estimated by the ratio 
$${M_n\over\mbox{average gap near $x_n$}}\sim {\log^2 x\over\log x}
\sim\log x \sim\log x_n;
$$

(iii) it's intuitively clear that we will almost always see $m_n$ exceeding the average count of primes in $[x,x+M_n]$ (for $x$ near $x_n$). That is,
$$
m_n > \log x_n \qquad\mbox{ for almost all } n.
$$

**What happens with $m_n/M_n$?**

We can expect that the ratio $m_n/M_n$ is bounded. If the ratio decreases to zero, then the decrease is surely not as fast as $1/\log x_n$. (But I would be very surprised to see a rigorous proof of this.)

Comment: Does the ratio $m_n/M_n$, if bounded, break Maier's theorem? (or at least show that it's mute.)

Comment: With (ii), you have "for almost all n" what is going on with the exceptions? I get that means $m_n \le \log x_n$, but a small count implies something with the gap size.

Comment: Under assumption that $\frac{M_{n+1}}{M_n} \le 2$, what is true? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831768/under-assumption-that-fracm-n1m-n-le-2-what-is-true?rq=1

Comment: I think Maier's theorem is compatible with everything in my answer. I do not think the additional assumption of $\frac{M_{n+1}}{M_n} \le 2$ changes anything in the answer. By saying "the ratio $m_n/M_n$ is bounded" I mean that there exists $C$ such that $m_n/M_n<C$.

Comment: In this answer, when I say "for almost all $n$", I actually further expect that the statement also may be plausible even "for all $n$ large enough". (The strengthening "for all $n$ large enough" just does not follow from my heuristic assumptions; e.g. we do not know how the Shanks conjecture might break, if it breaks at all -  so we simply assume that the Shanks conjecture is true for almost all maximal gaps, so $M_n\sim\log^2 x_n$ for almost all $n$.)